# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in /home/domain.com/domains/domain.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 531

Tags: php, plugins

Its showing the error in line no 531.When ever i opened my domain its showing this error -
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in /home/domain.com/domains/domain.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 531

I dont know how to solve this issue kindly help me in that -

```
    if ( empty( $arg ) ) {
        $arg[] = '';
    } elseif ( is_array( $arg[0] ) && 1 === count( $arg[0] ) && isset( $arg[0][0] ) && is_object( $arg[0][0] ) ) {
        // Backward compatibility for PHP4-style passing of `array( &$this )` as action `$arg`.
        $arg[0] = $arg[0][0];
    }

    $wp_filter[ $hook_name ]->do_action( $arg );

    array_pop( $wp_current_filter );
}

/**
 * Calls the callback functions that have been added to an action hook, specifying arguments in an array.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
```

basically 531 row is empty so i removed that line and save it but it didnot work for me kindly help me

Comment: Off-topic I know but I like the *Backward compatibility for PHP4-style passing* comment!

Comment: The last `}` doesn't belong to anything.